# SQL for number of customers placed orders within 6 months

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

- customers: id, joining_date
- orders: id, customer_id, order_date

I need to select the number of customers who placed orders within 6 months of joining date.
What I have done so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  
  FROM customers
  JOIN orders
    ON customers.id = orders.customer_id
    AND (
      orders.order_date BETWEEN customers.joining_date
      AND DateAdd(month,1,customers.joining_date)
    )
```

But I am getting

```
Error: column 'month' does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the SQL Server syntax
In PostgreSQL, you add an interval with `date + interval '1 month'`
So in your case, you should replace DateAdd by:

```
customers.joining_date + interval '6 month'
```

Comment: One more question will the answer includes the count of  value if customers.joining_date is null?

Answer (score 1):

Use this query that uses PostgreSQL syntax expression:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers JOIN orders ON customers.id =
>   orders.customer_id AND (orders.order_date BETWEEN
>   customers.joining_date AND (customers.joining_date + INTERVAL '1
>   month'));

Answer (score 0):

Your logic (attempts to) counts the number of *orders*, not the number of *customers*.  Here are two approaches:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)  
FROM customers c JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.id = o.customer_id AND
        o.order_date >= c.joining_date AND
        o.order_date < c.joining_date + interval '6 month';
```

Or more efficiently as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM customers c 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM orders o
              WHERE c.id = o.customer_id AND
                    o.order_date >= c.joining_date AND
                    o.order_date < c.joining_date + interval '6 month'
             );
```

Comment: customer.id is unique. so, there is need to use 'DISTINCT' right? Also, I am selecting count from customers. So, it should count the number of customers right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AJ . . . You need `COUNT(DISTINCT)` in the first query because the join on `ORDERS` could produce multiple rows for a given customer.  This is handled by the second version.